# List and show uploaded pdf files dynamically

Tags: uploads, pdf

I want to show all the PDFs for a specific WordPress page. I exactly want that the PDF documents will upload from the admin panel and I want to show all the PDFs in a page in the front-end dynamically. When I upload a new PDF from the admin panel, then the PDF will show automatically in the frontend. Is it possible to do that?

Here is the code that I tried:

```
<?php   
define('MYDIR','/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/');

if (!defined('MYDIR')) die ('Directory Is not correct or is not defined!');
$filesindir=scandir(MYDIR);
echo '<pre>';
$counter=0;
foreach($filesindir as $files)
{
     if ($files=='.pdf') continue;
     $counter++;
     echo "<a href=" . MYDIR . $files .  ">Download $files</a><br>";
}
echo "<br>Theris $counter PDF file(s)</pre>";
unset($files);
die;
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Mime_Type_Parameters

Answer (score 2):

## Possibilities to fetch attachments

WordPress saves files not only to a physical disk, but as well as `attachment` post type into your MySQL/MariaDB database. This means you have two possibilities to query for uploaded files and you have to chose what you need in which scenario/context.

### Filesystem only

To loop through all files or a specific type in a specific directory, you can use the `\FilesystemIterator` (PHP 5.3+ needed), then simply push the results to an `Array`/`[]`. In the following example we are looping through all PDF files in the directory determined by `wp_upload_dir()` [<sup>source</sup>](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir).

```
$extension = 'pdf';
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();

$files = new \FilesystemIterator( 
    $uploads['path'],
    \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS 
    | \FilesystemIterator::FOLLOW_SYMLINKS
);

$html = [];
foreach ( $files as $pdf )
{
    /** @noinspection PhpIncludeInspection */
    if ( 
        ! $files->isDir() 
        && $extension === $files->getExtension()
    )
        $html[] = $files->getRealPath();
}
```

You can then easily craft your final MarkUp using for e.g. native PHPs `explode()` function:

```
printf(
     "<ul><li>%s</li></ul>",
     explode( "</li><li>", $html )
);
```

Keep in mind that `wp_upload_dir()` does the following and therefore differs per environment and needs either the defaults or carefully set constant in your `wp-config.php` file.

> Depending on single- vs. multisite installs, the `uploads/` directory, determined by `UPLOADBLOGSDIR`, `BLOGUPLOADSDIR`, `UPLOADS` constants.

Also, in case you will want to loop more than one directory, you will want to use a [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) instead of the `\FilesystemIterator`. You can then wrap this Iterator in a `RecursiveIteratorIterator` for looping. The Directory Iterator inherits methods from `\FilesystemIterator`, which again inherits from `\DirectoryIterator`, so you should carefully read the PHP docs to see the full potential and possibilities you have at hand.

This means you can, as seen in the first example, symlink your `uploads` folder and keep it **outside the WordPress core folders** that you downloaded. Reason for that would be for e.g.

- automated deployments
- automated builds,
- builds done using *Composer*,
- version controled WordPress core,
- separate Filesystem backups (or rsync-ed) for your uploads
- …

All this of course highly depends on your setup and you will need to catch a lot of different setups here in case you plan to publicly distribute code that does what you need it to do.

**ProTip:** Consider returning just JSON data in case this is the result of an AJAX filesystem query.

**ProTip:** You can use `\DirectoryIterator`s methods [`getMTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getmtime.php) to get the last time a file was modified and [`getATime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getatime.php) to get the last time a file was accessed.

### Database and Filesystem query

The second method is to use a `\WP_Query` and query for a MIME-Type:

```
$files = new \WP_Query( [
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'application/pdf',
] );
```

Now you are able to loop through all `$files` and actually have `\WP_Post` elements at your hands. This means you can use ever method that you can use on normal posts like [`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_ID/), `the_title()`, etc.

Point is, that you are not only hitting the filesystem now, but as well the database, which is slow. Keep that in mind when going down this route. You should probably **not do that for all** attachments at once. Better [paginate the query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination) using an `offset` and the appropriate `pre_get_posts` filter (and remove the callback right after that).

Also keep in mind that the `application/pdf` MIME type is the [RFC 3778](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3778.txt) standard, which means you can rely on it – as long as there is no extension to the PDF type and a non-standard "X"-token in use, which would render it "unregistered", which is not that uncommon. More information in the [RFC 2045 paper](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-5.1).

> x-token := <The two characters "X-" or "x-" followed, with no intervening white space, by any token>

In full length:

> Beyond this syntax, the only syntactic constraint on the definition
> of subtype names is the desire that their uses must not conflict.
> That is, it would be undesirable to have two different communities
> using "Content-Type: application/foobar" to mean two different
> things.  The process of defining new media subtypes, then, is not
> intended to be a mechanism for imposing restrictions, but simply a
> mechanism for publicizing their definition and usage.  There are,
> therefore, two acceptable mechanisms for defining new media subtypes:

and then in detail:

> Private values (starting with "X-") may be defined
> bilaterally between two cooperating agents without
> outside registration or standardization. Such values
> cannot be registered or standardized.

### Conclusion

Personally I would only use the query for file types in case I need the title and meta data added by users when they upload files. From experience the UI still is confusing and people rarely complete those data sets. Also – again – only use it if you really need that data.